# Highstock: set xAxis as not "datetime"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am trying to populate a highchart with some dynamic data in my angularjs application. I am using the "highcharts-ng" directive for working the the highcharts.

https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

The data is typically of the following format:

x-axis (categories):

```
 [0, 0.0001001001001, 0.0002002002002, 0.0003003003003,
   0.0004004004004, 0.000500500500501, 0.000600600600601]
```

y-axis:

```
{
 name: value1, 
 data: [
     0, 2.27112321592e-7, 8.69358451877e-7, 
     0.00000192654087985, 0.00000339761308545, 
     0.0000052811192715, 0.00000757519580291
]}
```

The categories can contain thousands of values, and for each value in "x-axis category", there is a corresponding y-axis value

I have set the "x-axis" categories dynamically using the following code:
chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);

Some other relevant properties that I have set are:

```
$scope.chartConfig = {
    chart: {
        type:'spline'
    }
    options: {
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                turboThreshold: 51000,
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category', (I tried with 'linear' as well)
        allowDecimals: true,
        min: 0,
    },
    useHighStocks: true
};
```

However, I am still seeing that "x-axis" is showing the values as "datetime". Is there any way in which I can make the x-axis value a simple "decimal values" and not as datetime?

Also, since the x-axis values are decimal values, is it possible to display the corresponding scientific notation instead (i.e.  instead of showing 0.0003003003003, can we show 3.003e-04)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Kapil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Highstock only datetime axis type exists. In Highcharts you have linear/datetime/logarithmic and categorized types.

References:

- [Highcharts xAxis](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type) // type property
- [Highstock xAxis](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickWidth) // last element in docs