# how to remove scroll bar in drill down highchart

Tags: jquery, highcharts, scrollbars, drilldown

Below is my drill down chart, I want to remove the scroll bar while drill down event, and need the scroll bar again when we do  drill up event.

I tried below api's but it didn't help:

```
chart.scroller.scrollbar.hide();
chart.scroller.scrollbarGroup.hide();
```

scrollbarGroup.hide() - is removing the scroll bar but along with that **success** value also removing which I don't want.

My second problem is while loading first time - my scroll bar directly pointing to **user3** instead of **user1. But if I do drill down event and do drill up event its pointing to **user1** but not for the first time.

Any help would be really appreciated to resolve these two issues.

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqueryb/ndfk7vgd/15/)

Comment: but along with that success value also removing  is not clear

Comment: A very important thing is , Highstock has only dateTime type in xAxis. That's why your series is showing as datetime. yu are not filling categories with an array of items. refer documentation.. Simply use highcharts.js instead highstock

Comment: It seems like  highcharts.js  don't have scroll bar, that's the reason I went for hightstock.js

Comment: That's right , scrollbar is highstock's feature .but second thing is type:category in xAxis isn't supported by highstock. for that  you should defines categories as separate array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second problem: Call set extremes in load event to get extremes to 0,7 from the very beginning.

First problem: In drilldown event hide chart.scroller.scrollbar, chart.scroller.scrollbarGroup and change stroke-width of chart.scroller.scrollbarRifles, because hide doesn't work that well there. Update axis to set new min as 0 (or call setExtremes if you need to set min/max). In drillup event show previously hidden elements and set strok-width back to 1 for the last one.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ndfk7vgd/19/

```
// Create the chart
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            load: function (e) {
                this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0, 7);
            },
            drilldown: function (e) {
                this.xAxis[0].update({
                    min: 0
                });
                chart.scroller.scrollbar.hide();
                chart.scroller.scrollbarGroup.hide();
                chart.scroller.scrollbarRifles.attr({
                    'stroke-width': 0
                });
            },
            drillup: function (e) {
                chart.scroller.scrollbar.show();
                chart.scroller.scrollbarGroup.show();
                chart.scroller.scrollbarRifles.attr({
                    'stroke-width': 1
                });
                var _self = this.xAxis[0];
                setTimeout(function () {
                    _self.setExtremes(0, 7);
                }, 1);
            }
        }
    },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
The solution which I provided in below answer was based on the consideration that you are using highStock **but** A very important thing is , Highstock has **only dateTime type in xAxis**. That's why your series is showing as datetime. you are not filling categories with an array of items. refer documentation.. Simply use highcharts.js instead highstock 
also refer [Highstock: set xAxis as not "datetime"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20532540/highstock-set-xaxis-as-not-datetime)

use following code in drilldown

```
$( ".highcharts-scrollbar" ).css( "display", "none" );
    chart.scroller.xAxis.labelGroup.hide();
    chart.scroller.xAxis.gridGroup.hide();
    chart.scroller.series.hide();
    chart.scroller.scrollbar.hide();
    chart.scroller.scrollbarGroup.hide();
    chart.scroller.navigatorGroup.hide();
    chart.scroller.scrollbarRifles.hide();
    $.each( chart.scroller.elementsToDestroy, function ( i, elem ) {
        elem.hide();
    } );
```

for drillup part refer [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/ndfk7vgd/17/)

Comment: Thanks Nishith! But above solution is not my expected result.  The scrollbar itself looks different and in top its coming some additional value and all like **Zoom**, From and To Date etc..

Comment: you want range selectors,date filter also hidden ? add those things as well in function.

Comment: yeah! I want to hide and in y axis instead of user1, user 2 it showing Jan and some time - not sure why?

Comment: I used Highcharts.StockChart instead Highcharts.Chart..that's why you seen extended things

Comment: Got it. I converted **Highcharts.StockChart ** with **Highcharts.Chart**  but drill down event is not working